# How to cope with studying on online platforms

Tags: online-learning, covid-19

I would like to know about any suggestions that the community can give about coping with online school. I have both school and my coaching classes. Hence the screen time is too high and I also require time for self study. The syllabus covered in school is the same as in the coaching institute. The teaching of my coaching is better, but attendance in school is compulsory (for internal marks). Also, currently both are through online platforms itself, so let me know how to manage my time. (School timing 6 hrs each day for 6 days a week and coaching timing 7.5 hrs in a week)

Comment: I'm afraid you might not find a good answer here as it depends on individual factors.

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Comment: You should discuss this with your school and your coach: they are the ones that can do something to change the situation.

Comment: I think it might help to add a subject and the level of study here. To much screen time may be a common problem, but the solutions vary according to what else you could be doing. For example, if the work requires coding, some quiet multitasking would be a good way to help you get through lectures that are repeating material. Unit tests really only require half attention to write.

Comment: @Clumsy cat...I am studying high school level physics, maths, chemistry, social science, mental ability, information technology and a couple of languages.

Comment: Voting to close since high-school level teaching and learning is off-topic on this SE site, which is for postgraduate studies and university-level teaching.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Clearly it's going to be a sub optimal use of time to attend both lessons and pay full attention. I will assume the coaching classes are happening because the school classes are sub-optimal, therefor in the school classes, you need a second activity to occupy you. It needs to be something that wont get you in too much trouble, so it needs to be strongly related to the class.
Using the information in the comment;

> I am studying high school level physics, maths, chemistry, social science, mental ability, information technology and a couple of languages

Of these subjects, I know that maths chemistry and physics are mainly exam based, and from almost any given exam, there are lots of past papers available. You should print out exam questions of the appropriate subject and try to work through them during class. Printed exam questions, rather than reading from a screen, so that it doesn't look like you're browsing the web.

You must be able to hear the class as you do it, and if someone asks you what you are doing, apologise and answer honestly. Say you feel you have a good grasp of the material, and want to practice for the exam. Most teachers will find this answer acceptable.

Comment: Thank you for the help!!

Comment: @Anonymous it this answered your question you can accept the answer by pressing the tick to the left, so that it goes green.